# Access DU member's named fields

Tags: f#, field, discriminated-union

How can I access the named fields of a discriminated union's member?

Example:

```
type Point = | Point of x : int * y : int
let p = Point(3, 1)
// how to access x-value or y-value of p here?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, unions with named fields work just like any other union type: You would access the fields via `match`:

```
let x, y = 
    match p with 
    | Point (x1, y1) -> x1, y1
```

[The F# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions) also mentions a way of matching only some named parameters. In your case, this means you can write:

```
let xOnly = 
    match p with 
    | Point (x = x1) -> x1
```

If all you have is a single case, see the answer by @p.s.w.g. The code in that answer is general for all discriminated unions. For singleton unions with named fields, you can use the special syntax shown above and write:

```
let Point(x = myX) = p
```

This binds the value of field `x` to `myX`.

**PS** as per the comments: Why can you not read out the fields right away, by doing `p.x`? You can think of a discriminated union as a small object hierarchy (and use it such, see the [discriminated union documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions): "You can often use a discriminated union as a simpler alternative to a small object hierarchy"). Consider the following DU:

```
type Shape = | Circle of r: float | Square of float
```

You can view `Shape` as the superclass. `Circle` and `Square` are two derived classes, each with a single `float` property. Each instance of `Circle` or `Square` that you create will be upcast to be a `Shape`.

With that, it becomes clear why you can't read out the fields immediately: you first need to establish which of the derived classes you are looking at, only after the cast to the right subclass you can read out the fields.

This object hierarchy view matches very closely to how DUs are handled internally by F#: If you look at the DU type in reflection, you will see two nested types that have the same name as your union cases:

```
> typeof<Shape>.GetNestedTypes()
|> Seq.iter (fun t -> 
    let p = t.GetProperties() 
    let s = 
        p
        |> Array.map (fun p -> sprintf "%s: %s" p.Name p.PropertyType.Name) 
        |> String.concat "; "
    printfn "Nested type %s: %i Properties %s" t.Name p.Length s
);;
Nested type Tags: 0 Properties 
Nested type Circle: 4 Properties r: Double; Tag: Int32; IsCircle: Boolean; IsSquare: Boolean
Nested type Square: 4 Properties Item: Double; Tag: Int32; IsCircle: Boolean; IsSquare: Boolean
```

The actual data lives in properties of the subclass. For `Circle`, we used named fields, you see the property `r`. For `Square`, we have data in the `Item` property (or `Item1`, `Item2` if there were multiple arguments). The rest are compiler generated:  the numeric `Tag` field that will be used to quickly distinguish between the subclasses, and two bool properties for subclass checks.

The superclass itself only has compiler-generated properties:

```
>     typeof<Shape>.GetProperties()
    |> Seq.iter (fun p -> printfn "Property %s" p.Name);;
Property Tag
Property IsCircle
Property IsSquare
```

Comment: isn't there any shorter syntax for achieving something like `let p2 = Point(p.x, p.y)` ?

Comment: In the general case, with multiple union cases: no. `p` can be an object that represents the `Point` case, but also some other union case. If you want to think of it in OOP terms: `p` is an instance of the superclass, but you are trying to access the fields of a derived class. The `match` does the equivalent of the cast, and makes the fields accessible.

Comment: @no_mindset, if you only have a single case and you're interested in shorter syntax, use records, not unions.

Comment: That superclass / derived class explanation is worthy of being in the answer, not just in a comment. I'm going to steal that to explain F# DUs to my colleagues. Thanks for a great analogy, especially because it's literally true if you examine the generated IL code for discriminated unions.

Answer (score 5):

For single-case discriminated unions like your example, you don't need to use a `match-with` expression. You could just do this:

```
let (Point (x, y)) = p
printf "%i" x // 3
```

Or to just get `x` and ignore `y`:

```
let (Point (x, _)) = p
printf "%i" x // 3
```